# Django Model Admin

Tags: python, django, model, admin

How I can display in the Model Admin only the login user and not all Users? Now the user can see only its own data but at the same time can see other users in the dropdown when editing.
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj3KL.png)

**Models.py**

```py
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,db_column="user",null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL
)
```

**Admin.py**

```py
def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(Museum_ItemAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

The problem is when logging in as "Peter" I can see and manage all users. The question is how I can see only Peter and not be able to see or change any other users?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Are you using django-admin as frontend or you just what an API responces?

Comment: I am using the Django-Admin as a frontend, where users they can log in and at their content, and at the same time, they can view their own content only. The problem is that the login user can see and select other users. What I need to do is that login not to able to select or see other users. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:-

You need to filter, according to your key

**admin.py**

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # list_display = ('username', 'is_active')
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs.filter(is_active = True)
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

For more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer and works for me, thanks for your help

```
 exclude = ('user',)

def save_form(self, request, form, change):
    obj = super().save_form(request, form, change)
    if not change:
        obj.user = request.user
    return obj

def get_queryset(self, request):
   qs = super().get_queryset(request)
   if request.user.is_superuser:
       return qs
        
   return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```